# How to pass array into ReactSelect

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of strings named **times**. Which is formatted like this:
[image]

I passed it onto a component as props but I am having a hard time passing it onto the ReactSelect component.

```
const TimeInput=(
            <div>
                <ReactSelect
                        className='react-select react-select-top'
                        classNamePrefix='react-select'
                        id='displayLanguage'
                        menuIsOpen={this.state.openMenu}
                        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                        styles={reactStyles}
                        **options={this.props.times}**
                        clearable={false}
                        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                        onMenuClose={this.handleMenuClose}
                        onMenuOpen={this.handleMenuOpen}
                        aria-labelledby='changeInterfaceLanguageLabel'
                    />
            </div>
        )
```

I get this error when I try to pass the times array into ReactSelect (please ignore the errors after that as those are functions I have not worked on yet ie. handleMenuClose:

[image]

Comment: I suggest [reading the documentation](https://react-select.com/home) for examples and details of how to use this component correctly.

Comment: the `options` property should be assigned as `[{ value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' }]`, i.e. as array of object. Can you plz check if this is how its passed to ReactSelect?

Comment: Hello Rohit, no that's not how I passed it. I just passed the array as is. Do you know how to convert it to that format?

Comment: `this.props.times.map(value => ({ value, label: value }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options` prop takes in an array of JSON objects with the keys `value` and `label`, so you need to convert your array of times into that format.

One way to do that is mapping

```
// Before your render function

const timeOptions = this.props.times.map((timeString) => {
  // Ideally you can change the value to something different that is easier to keep track of like the UTC offset
  return {
      value: timeString,
      label: timeString
    }
  }
);

// In render function
// Now pass in timeOptions as the prop for your ReactSelect
...
<ReactSelect
...
  options={timeOptions}
...>
```

Comment: Just a quick question, when I do onChange for this. What parameter would my onChange function take in. ie. OnChange = ( _________) = this.setState({timeInput:e.target.value})

Comment: Your onChange will recieve an `event`, so you can retrieve the selected value with `event.target.value`. It looks like your code addresses the event as `e` so you would use `onChange = (e) => this.setState({timeInput:e.target.value})`

Comment: Hey I did this and it seems to work fine, the issue I have is the value being passed onto ReactSelect isnt the correct type. I passed in  value={this.state.manualTimezoneInput} for ReactSelect (the value argument was not included in my initial question sorry about that)

Comment: How is `this.state.manualTimezoneInput` assigned or what does it hold? I would need to see the code that sets that state to understand